# Will $\arccos(x)$ always give me the angle I am looking for?

Tags: trigonometry

Perhaps a dumb question, but I've never had trigonometry classes so I am much behind every one else.

If $\cos\theta = x$, will $\arccos(x)$ always give me the "first" angle in positive direction with the corresponding cosine value?

How does it decide which one to give as there are infinitely many?

Comment: Yes it does, normally arccos is defined for the angles $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: When you say "how does it decide" are you referring to the mathematical definition, or a computer implementation of the function?

Answer (score 1):

The $\cos$ function takes in any real number, and spits out a number from $-1$ to $1$. As a whole, it is not invertible since it fails the horizontal line test. For example, $\cos (\pi/2)=\cos(3\pi/2)=0.$ This means that $\arccos(0)$ is ambiguous. It could be $\pi/2$ or  $3\pi/2$ or infinitely many other angles.

To fix this, we limit the domain of $\cos\theta$ to only allow values where $0\le\theta\le\pi$. On this interval, $\cos\theta$ passes the horizontal line test and has an inverse. This means that $\arccos x$ will take in a value $-1\le x\le1$ and spit out a unique angle $0\le\theta\le\pi$ such that $\cos\theta=x$.